# Using Collectors.toList instead of forEach and a new ArrayList

Tags: java

I have the following Java 8+ code (on Java 14).  I have a (terminal) `forEach` call and I am adding each mapped object to a newly created `ArrayList`.

Is there a more idiomatic way this could be rewritten using `Collectors.toList()` and potentially `flatMap`?

```
public List<SearchSuggestion> suggest() {
   List<Watchlist> watchlists = someService.findAll();
   List<SearchSuggestion> suggestions = new ArrayList<>();

   watchlists.forEach(watchlist -> watchlist.getWatchlistItems()
            .forEach(watchlistItem -> {
                suggestions.add(mapToSearchSuggestion(watchlistItem.getInstrument()));
            })
   );
   return suggestions;
}

private SearchSuggestion mapToSearchSuggestion(Instrument instrument) {
    return SearchSuggestion.builder()
            .symbol(instrument.getSymbol())
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one way using `flatMap` and `Collectors.toList()`:

```
public List<SearchSuggestion> suggest() {
   return someService.findAll().stream()
            .flatMap(wl->wl.getWatchlistItems().stream())
            .map(wli->mapToSearchSuggestion(wli.getInstrument()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

However (since this is Code Review) the method `mapToSearchSuggestion` seems more appropriate to be in the class `Instrument`. If you can move it there then the function becomes:

```
public List<SearchSuggestion> suggest() {
    return watchlists.stream()
            .flatMap(wl ->wl.getWatchlistItems().stream())
            .map(WatchlistItem::getInstrument)
            .map(Instrument::mapToSearchSuggestion)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

`Instrument` class:

```
public class Instrument {
    //...
    public SearchSuggestion mapToSearchSuggestion() {
        return SearchSuggestion.builder().symbol(getSymbol()).build();
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to maybe simplify the syntax further using `.map(WatchListItem::getInstrument)` in the second example?

Comment: @BusyAnt yes thanks for the hint, I updated it.

Comment: Thank you!  I will try out the first suggestion.  The second part may not apply in my case because I will be adding more logic to that method.  I feel like the IDE should have an intention to suggest this.

Comment: @marc I disagree that the method `mapToSearchSuggestion` should be in `Instrument`.. Does Instrument even need to know about `SearchSuggestion`? I think not. Better to extract to a `Util`/`Converter`/`Builder` type of class